# Сообщение участнику об оскорбительном поведении

Tags: предложение, модерация, инструменты-модератора

Предыстория такая. Мы все обычно общаемся друг с другом на профессиональном уровне и не скатываемся до оскорблений даже когда спорим о политике или фичах компиляторов. И даже когда сталкиваемся с новичком, который упорно не желает нас понять.

К сожалению, не все так умеют. Периодически кто-нибудь скатывается до оскорблений. Чаще это новые участники, не успевшие пропитаться нашей субкультурой, реже - упорные "старички". Кто-то не может держать себя в руках, а кто-то не считает нужным.

Как правило, тревога об оскорбительном сообщении доходит до модератора, который отправляет участнику личное сообщение, которое также может сопровождаться блокировкой учетной записи (баном). Блокировка без сообщения невозможна.

Сообщение это, на мой взгляд, отправляется от имени всего сообщества. Мы же все стараемся поддерживать высокий уровень, а не только один какой-нибудь <s>вахтёр</s> модератор.

У сообщения есть шаблон. Это перевод англоязычного варианта с некоторыми дополнениями:

> Мы хотим сообщить вам о том, что мы обнаружили несколько отметок об оскорбительном содержании ваших сообщений. Мы знаем, каково это. Все, кто когда-либо пытался общаться в Сети, сталкивались с желанием излить гнев на своего собеседника. Дружеское напоминание: [все участники должны использовать профессиональный и цивилизованный подход в общении на наших сайтах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). Если другой участник каким-либо образом оскорбил вас, не уподобляйтесь его поведению. Просто поставьте отметку рядом с его сообщением, чтобы привлечь внимание модератора, и продолжайте работу.
>
> К сожалению, мы вынуждены ограничить доступ к вашей учётной записи на {N} дней. Сайт был создан для того, чтобы делиться знаниями с коллегами, а не для выяснения отношений и тем более не для выпуска агрессии. Пожалуйста, будьте более вежливы с другими участниками сообщества.

Я обычно удаляю его и переписываю с нуля, потому что исходный текст я понимаю примерно так:

> С прискорбием сообщаем вам о том, что по нашему великому недоразумению недавно вами кого-то оскорбило. Мы вам очень сочувствуем. Вам действительно тяжело переживать гнев, раздражение и все остальные эмоции. Вот вам ссылка на страницу справки, уж простите что мы так незаметно разместили справку. Наверное, это другой участник вас спровоцировал, оскорблял вас и выводил из себя. В следующий раз, пожалуйста, просто оставьте тревогу - уж мы с ним разберемся!
>
> Простите пожалуйста, но нам придётся вас побанить. Мы не виноваты, нас менеджер сообщества заставляет так делать.

Что это вообще такое? Если бы я получил такое сообщение (исходный текст, а не мою интерпретацию), я бы подумал, что модератор связан по рукам и ногам десятью соглашениями о толерантности и непротивлении злу. А слабость и виноватая позиция провоцируют агрессию, поэтому я думаю, что на некоторых участников такое сообщение может повлиять в обратную сторону.

Перейду к делу. Чтобы это сообщение было адекватно своей цели и действительно исходило от лица всего сообщества, давайте вместе его переработаем. Пожалуйста, предлагайте свои варианты. Не обещаю, что какой-то из них будет использован дословно, но итоговый вариант мы соберем именно из них.

Comment: Вполне ниче так исходный вариант же. Смысл - меньшей кровью добиться результата. К чему лишний раз человека раздражать/оскорблять?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian раздражать или оскорблять человека не нужно. Но и вставать в слабую позицию и просить тоже неверно. Слабость провоцирует агрессию. Считаю, что нужно спокойно и уверенно объяснить, что у нас так не принято и человек может либо исправить своё поведение, либо уйти.

Comment: Вы конечно меня извините, но мне кажется принимать вежливость в купе с адекватным действием (баном), за слабость, это уж как-то совсем по варварски. Думаете, имеют место тут такие пользователи?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Я имею в виду например вот эту сострадательную фразу: `Мы знаем, каково это.` Да какая разница, знаю ли я, каково нарушителю правил? Судья же не говорит подсудимому "парень, я знаю каково это, грабить/убивать/совершать акты насильственного характера с гусями". Не знаю я, у меня психика немного иначе работает.

Comment: Зато это делают наши родители/друзъя, да и вообще помоему это принято в цивилизованном обществе. Все таки не уголовное же преступление. Когда ты кого то случайно толкаешь в магазине, и он тебе говорит "извините", мы же понимаем, что он себя виноватым не считает, и это только вопрос вежливости и стремления решить проблему мирным путем. Может, конечно, я идеализирую слишком ))

Comment: С "Дружеское напоминание" и "Мы знаем, каково это" в общем то согласен, можно на более формальное что-то сменить.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian ну да, это нормальная ситуация. Реакция должна быть адекватна поступку. Мы как правило не баним за какие-нибудь безадресные маты, когда человек просто эмоции выпустил. И за негативную оценку кода тоже. Только за целенаправленные оскорбления в адрес личностей участников сайта.

Answer (score 3):

> Мы хотим сообщить вам о том, что обнаружили несколько отметок об оскорбительном содержании ваших сообщений. Все участники должны использовать профессиональный и цивилизованный подход в общении на наших сайтах. Если другой участник каким-либо образом оскорбил вас, не уподобляйтесь его поведению. Просто поставьте отметку рядом с его сообщением, чтобы привлечь внимание модератора.
>
> В связи с этим, мы вынуждены ограничить доступ к вашей учётной записи на {N} дней. Сайт был создан для того, чтобы делиться знаниями с коллегами, а не для выяснения отношений и тем более не для выпуска агрессии. Пожалуйста, будьте более вежливы с другими участниками сообщества.

Comment: Мне нравится. У меня в принципе и получилось похоже (см. альтернативный вариант: там много объяснений, но сам текст сделан более кратким)

Answer (score 3):

Свой ответ я разобью на несколько частей.

В первой части я опишу то, что мне не нравится в типовом письме, которое привёл Николай.

Во-второй части я опишу общую схему своего ответа.

Ну и наконец выдам законченную формулировку, чтобы можно было посмотреть конкретику.

"Букф" в преамбуле будет много, кому нужна конкретика -- сразу мотайте вниз.

Итак. Чем плохо типовое письмо?

Во-первых, действительно есть разница культурных контекстов. Мы реально кажемся англосаксам дикими варварами, которые сразу бьют топором по голове и не знают слова 'please'. 
Вопрос о том, как оказалось, что великая русская цивилизация Достоевского и Толстого с её гуманистическими идеалами так плохо стыкуется с подчёркнутой вежливостью американо-европейского стиля я оставлю для более подходящего сообщества на stackexchage. ;) Здесь лишь хочу высказать очень сильный тезис: я предлагаю на ру-СО использовать наш культурный контекст, а не использовать чужой. Уверен, что мнения по этому поводу могут сильно разделиться и поляризовать сообщество, однако специально формулирую в жесткой формулировке, чтобы попробовать выяснить точку зрения других.

Во-вторых, у меня большие претензии к самому письму в плане логической структуры материала. Предмет разговора несколько раз непоследовательно прыгает туда-сюда. Вот как выглядит план письма, вам он кажется логичным, понятным, одно вытекает из другого? Мне кажется, что нет.

План:
1. На вас пришли жалобы, что вы ругаетесь матом
2. Понимаем, как тяжело, когда кругом одни уроды и хочется кого-то стукнуть.
3. Но если так случилось, что кругом уроды -- вы-то будьте морально стойки, крепки духом и не срывайтесь
4. А вас придётся забанить.

Вот этот пункт три он слишком длинный и не пришей кобыле хвост. И пункты 2 и 3 выглядят совершенно ненужными с той точки зрения, что нужно говорить по делу, а не рассуждать о посторонних вещах типа цвета рогов у пони и формы перистых облаков. По делу должны быть пункт 1 и 4, а 2 и 3 просто притянуты за уши.

В принципе, моя критика письма закончилась, перехожу к предложениям.

Я предлагаю не ориентироваться на чужие лекала, а составить письмо уместное для нашего сообщества. Действительно, многими такая позиция воспринимается как слабая. Поэтому письмо должно быть именно в стиле "тут жалобы что ты ругаешься матом - это правда - ты забанен". Никаких "прогибов", всё чисто по делу. Можно отсылки к формальным правилам сделать, это тоже по делу.

А второе моё предложение по письму заключается в том, что мы вообще-то можем обойти противоречие между культурными лекалами. Письмо западное многим не нравится, но и то, что привёл я не устроит очень многих. Пытаться усидеть на двух стульях -- очень шаткая позиция.
Но мы сделаем вот как. Мы будем апеллировать к совершенно третьей вещи. Ру-со как и большой со -- это сообщество инженерно-техническое с чётким уклоном на обмен знаниями, общением по делу. Войско должно быть непобедимым, наука должна быть передовой, а инженер должен... ммммм, ну не знаю, но уж не ругаться точно. Вот собственно и весь фокус: мы не копировали толерантность исходного текста, но и нашли общую вещь.

Итого, у меня получается конкретный ответ вот в каком виде:

> Мы получили несколько сигналов об оскорбительном содержании ваших
>   сообщений.
>
> [Stack Overflow на русском](http://ru.stackoverflow.com) — сообщество
>   специалистов, которое ориентировано на обмен знаниями, в своём общении
>   мы придерживаемся [профессионального и цивилизованного
>   подхода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).
>
> В связи с этим мы вынуждены приостановить доступ к вашей учётной
>   записи на {N} дней.

Comment: `#define оскорбления бан`. :) Мне нравится этот вектор переработки письма, коротко и по сути.

Comment: Пока вижу только одну альтернативную версию - от Владимира. Если сравнивать именно конкретные формулировки (а не подход), то у нас многое совпало (сожаления, которые расцениваются как слабость заменены на логическую связку "поэтому", "в связи"). Ограничить -- мне нравится больше приостановить (значит, не обрубаем навсегда, не казним). У меня только упор на максимально короткое письмо, у него подлиннее. Вот "сигналов" -- это я наверное зря, надо было оставить "отметок", а я какой-то новый термин выдумал. Но оно реально тут лучше смотрелось.

Comment: Что касается терминов, кнопка [edit] доступна всегда. Можете взять да исправить )

Comment: @NickVolynkin Лучше объясните, как сделать ответ общим. Я предлагал Владимиру не один общий ответ сделать, а сначала посмотреть какие вообще концепты писем будут. Но вот на этом этапе я объяснил свой концепт и не против если кто-то его улучшит. Комментарии здесь -- уже лишь пояснения к авторскому замыслу.

Comment: Один общий и не надо делать, если кто-то хочет свой вариант предложить - пусть предлагает отдельно. Как я уже писал, `Не обещаю, что какой-то из них будет использован дословно, но итоговый вариант мы соберем именно из них.`

Comment: На мой взгляд, в таком сообщение будет потеряна суть: нам не нужно блокировать учетную запись, нам нужно чтобы никто не ругался. Скорее всего, сорвавшийся участник, просто не правильно понял социальную ситуацию. Наша задача, как сообщества, предложить наше объяснение того, где именно была допущена ошибка, и рассказать, как в следующий раз поступать в подобных ситуациях. Взаимодействие в Интернете не заканчивается на SOru, и мне лично бы хотелось, чтобы культура общения нашего сообщества была перенята повсеместно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Я осознанно убирал из текстовок фрагмент пояснения "зачем мы блокируем" (или гипотетический фрагмент "если вы не согласны - можете подать на апелляцию через кнопку..."): на мой взгляд в эмоционально взвинченном человеке это только лишний повод продолжить дискуссию в негативных направлениях (от "а могли бы и не блокировать" до "и вы тоже уроды"). Я не противопоставляю свою правду вашей: и у вас тоже здравые мысли написаны.

Comment: Мне не очень нравится. Я вот прочитал текст, и он для меня значит: «На вас стукнули, поэтому мы отправляем вас в бан». Это — плохой, неверный мессидж. Правильнее было бы такой: «Ваше общение с другими содержит оскорбительные сообщения. Мы проверили, например, вот они (список). Поэтому вам бан. То, что они оскорбительные, не обсуждается, то, что ваш собеседник тоже не ангел — не оправдание, он скоро тоже попадёт в бан.»

Comment: @VladD Об этом не говорится ни в одном шаблоне: ни в текущем, ни в предлагаемом. Списка за что - нет. Обсуждаема ли блокировка, есть ли механизм апелляции -- я просто не в курсе, как оно выглядит у модераторов. Мне кажется, что этого нет.

Comment: @AK: Да, конечно. Но это не отменяет изложенные соображения, как мне кажется.

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, сообщение можно улучшить, но лишь незначительно. Текущая формулировка и, что самое главное, на мой взгляд, тон изложения соответствуют ситуации.

**Как выглядит типичная ситуация, приводящая к блокировке?**

1. *Ситуация А: знаток против изучающего (зачастую, нового участника сообщества)*. Изучающий некорректно или комично описывает проблему в вопросе. Знаток, с присущей уверенностью в себе, оставляет уточняющий комментарий, который, к сожалению, сформулирован двусмысленно: с одной стороны он полезен и отражает недостаток вопроса, с другой – поддевает, показывает некомпетентность автора вопроса. Далеко не все, кто задают плохо поставленные вопросы новички в профессии. У них не меньше уверенности, чем у знатока. Результат – грубый ответ в комментарии и отторжение к сообществу. Все–таки, человек обращается к сообществу за подсказкой, находясь в процессе решения прикладной профессиональной задачи, а не участвует в конкурсе комедиантов. По сути: *виноват провокатор, а блокировку получает поддавшийся на провокацию*.
2. *Ситуация Б: знаток против знатока*. Обычно происходит в случае расширенной дискуссии в комментариях к «скользкому» вопросу, решение которого возможно несколькими «оптимальными» способами. Каждый настаивает на своей позиции. Когда доводы начинают повторяться, кто-то не выдерживает и начинает откровенно провоцировать. Конечно же, «оппонент» за словом в карман не полезет. Снова *блокировку получает тот, кто поддался на провокацию*.

Случаи, когда кто–то ни с того ни с сего начинает оскорблять коллег единичны, и по большей части связанны с потерей доступа к учётной записи.

**Зачем вообще блокировать доступ к учетной записи?**

Следуя этой логике, как мне кажется, отправляемое сообщение отражает действительность: да, прямые оскорбления использовал именно блокируемый участник, но в нормальном состоянии он бы этого никогда не сделал. Что еще более важно, **смысл блокировки в данном случае, не «наказать», а дать отдохнуть от сообщества, взглянуть на ситуацию трезво со стороны**, чтобы «завтра не было стыдно», и по истечению блокировки участник мог все еще чувствовать себя частью сообщества

**Позиция силы**

Цель проекта «в себе» – дружное сообщество (т. е. реальные люди), в котором каждый энтузиаст программирования сможет найти для себя поддержку со стороны коллег.

Модератор – это участник, наиболее заинтересованный в развитии сообщества. Главная задача модератора, на мой взгляд – быть достойным примером для остальных, помогать коллегам в трудную минуту не только и не столько своими знаниями, сколько обычным человеческим взаимопониманием и поддержкой.

Модераторы – не исполнительный и, тем более, не судебный орган сообщества. Наиболее подходящее, на мой взгляд, аналогия из реальной жизни – медицинский персонал, так как именно модераторы, ночью, пока все спят, помогают сообществу быть здоровым, отчищая сайт от спама, ругани и другого вредоносного шума.

Никакой «позиции силы» в сообщении быть не может.

**Но сила-то все таки есть!**

И находится она в руках модераторов. Никакой другой участник не может заблокировать кого-либо.

Блокировка – это экстренный случай, произошедший по вине сообщества, но блокировку получает не все, а лишь один участник (либо несколько, в крайних случаях). Мы все вместе не смогли своевременно объяснить некоторым коллегам, умным образованным разработчикам программного обеспечения, как следует реагировать на подобные ситуации.

---

Я крайне симпатизирую многим участникам сообщества, которые проявляют рассудительность, толерантность, спокойствие и сдержанность. Любая провокацию в их сторону (как внутри сообщества, так и на внешних ресурсах) заканчивается тем, что они получают еще одного помощника (и возможно друга), вместо оппонента. Считая их примером и стараясь перенять их стиль общения, полагаю, что текущая формулировка соответствует положению дел и достигает поставленных целей.

Comment: Очень аргументированный ответ, спасибо.

Comment: А почему у Вас тире вместо дефисов? :)

Comment: `в нормальном состоянии он бы этого никогда не сделал` - с этим я не могу полностью согласиться. Для некоторых раздражение и гнев являются нормальными, привычными состояниями при общении в интернете.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Полностью согласен. С другой стороны, поведение человека зависит от окружение, в котором он находится. Мы, сообщество, создаем атмосферу знаний на сайте, мы же можем и создать атмосферу вражды.

Comment: Я с телефоном, не могу прочитать сообщение в приватном чате. Там что-то срочное или часа четыре подождет?

Comment: Нет, срочного ничего нет. Просто детективное расследование использования нескольких учетных записей.